# Custom Applicative Maybe

Tags: haskell

Tying to implement Applicative of same nature as Maybe.
Got tons of errors on compliation, most like

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘FixMePls b’
            with actual type ‘Maybe a1’
```

The code is as follows

```
data FixMePls a = FixMe | Pls a deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Monoid a => Monoid (FixMePls a) where
  mempty = Nothing
  mappend m Nothing = m
  mappend Nothing m = m
  mappend (Pls a) (Pls a') = Pls (mappend a a')

instance Applicative FixMePls where
  pure = Pls
  Nothing <*> _ = Nothing
  _ <*> Nothing = Nothing
  Pls f <*> Pls a = Pls f a


main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn("Weee!!!1!")
```

Any hints on what I'm doing wrong are welcome. I suspect it's datatype declaration, but not sure how to fix it.

Comment: It's telling you that it's expecting a `FixMePls b` (ie either a `FixMe` or a `Pls`) but it got a `Maybe a` (ie a `Just` or a `Nothing`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
data FixMePls a = FixMe | Pls a deriving (Eq, Show)
```

is ok nothing wrong with that one

```
instance Monoid a => Monoid (FixMePls a) where
  mempty = Nothing
  mappend m Nothing = m
  mappend Nothing m = m
  mappend (Pls a) (Pls a') = Pls (mappend a a')
```

here you start to mix `Maybe` and `FixmePls` - `Nothing` is a constructor for `Maybe` whereas `Fixme` is the one you need.

```
instance Monoid a => Monoid (FixMePls a) where
  mempty = FixMe
  mappend m FixMe = m
  mappend FixMe m = m
  mappend (Pls a) (Pls a') = Pls (mappend a a')
```

I am ommiting the applicative instance - as it should be quite similar, if you have problems - I spotted a parenthization error ;)